# PostgreSQL importing CSV fails on NULL fields

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to import into PostgreSQL DB a CSV file where some of the NULL values are represented by "". The command for copying on those fields crashes on those points (NULL values that are represented in the CSV as "").

My command to copy this is:

```
echo "Creating table module_telemetry"
psql -U $2 $3 < ./bin/sql/module_telemetry.sql
echo "Copying files for table module_telemetry"
psql -U $2 $3 -c "\copy module_telemetry from ./bin/telemetry/2020-08-01.csv delimiter ',' 
csv header;"
```

The error I am getting:

```
Copying files for table module_telemetry
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY module_telemetry, line 2, column gsm_a1: ""
```

I have tried the following:

I have replaced the supposed null value represented in the CSV like so: "" to \N with no success.

I have tried to do the same (out of hopelessness) and converted the CSV value representing NULL from "" to the following: NULL, null, "NULL", "null", "\N" to no avail.

I would be very thankful to anyone that has come already across this problem and managed to resolve it - by importing the null values instead of getting an error message.

Comment: Have you tried the [`NULL` option of `COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)? "*Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is an **unquoted** empty string in CSV format*". Also try `FORCE_NULL`.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for your comment. I am using the bash command. I have read that this can be done but those are PostgreSQL specific commands but that does not apply to me since my case is slightly different. Thanks for help

Comment: `psql`'s [`\copy` has exactly the same options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY)

Comment: As Bergi stated the meta-command `\copy` support exactly the same option of the `SQL` `COPY`.  What you could do is edit the CSV file replacing  `""`  with nothing, you can't use `""` as an unquoted empty string. Or you could use the NULL option to specifies the string that represents a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting so many comments. I managed to resolve the issue and the issue was different. Turns out that the csv first line (header) was the problem.
Although my command informs about it being included (unless there is something I do not understand):

```
psql -U $2 $3 -c "\copy module_telemetry from 
./bin/telemetry/2020-08-01.csv delimiter ',' 
csv header;"
```

I had to delete the header from each file and suddenly all went through. It was enough the null values were represented with empty space so:

```
value,,,another value,,,
```